# UIImagePickerController - crop picture to circle

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

Ho do I crop circle images with Image picker controller?

The pictures I'm displaying in my projects are round using the code below

```
 CALayer *image = profileImageView.layer;
        [image  setCornerRadius:50];
        [image  setMasksToBounds:YES];

        [image setBorderColor:[[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor]];
        [image setBorderWidth:5];
```

So far I have this code to crop images but it only makes them square

```
   - (void)showPhotoLibary
    {
        if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
              UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum] == NO)) {
            return;
        }

        UIImagePickerController *mediaUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        mediaUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

        // Displays saved pictures from the Camera Roll album.
        mediaUI.mediaTypes = @[(NSString*)kUTTypeImage];

        // Hides the controls for moving & scaling pictures
        mediaUI.allowsEditing = YES;


        mediaUI.delegate = self;


        [self presentViewController:mediaUI animated:YES completion:nil];
    }


    - (void) imagePickerController: (
                                     UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info {

        UIImage *originalImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        self.profileImageView.image = originalImage;



        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if u added `QuartzCore framework` to your project.
then u can do somthing like below
import `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` .m or .h file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
   [self.profileImageView.layer setCornerRadius:50];
   [self.profileImageView.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
   [self.profileImageView.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor whiteColor]CGColor]];
   [self.profileImageView.layer setBorderWidth:5];
 }

- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController *) picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary *) info 
 {
   UIImage *originalImage = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]; //it returns the edited image, 
   self.profileImageView.image = originalImage;
   [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

 }
```

Answer (score 2):

import `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` inyour.h file

```
   self.profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width/2;  //or 20.0
   self.profileImageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

Import the "QuartzCore framework" to get access to the "`.cornerRadius` property" of your `UIView` or `UIImageView`.

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Also manually add it to your project's Frameworks folder. Add this method to your view controller or wherever you need it:

```
-(void)setRoundedView:(UIImageView *)roundedView toDiameter:(float)newSize;
{
    CGPoint saveCenter = roundedView.center;
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(roundedView.frame.origin.x, roundedView.frame.origin.y, newSize, newSize);
    roundedView.frame = newFrame;
    roundedView.layer.cornerRadius = newSize / 2.0;
    roundedView.center = saveCenter;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I want the actual cropper that know is a square by default to display a round circle so the user can crop the image themselves as a circle with the same measurements. Does it make sense?

Comment: @user3615707 : So you want that a circular view whose dimensions can be changed by a user and image is cropped accordingly ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the circle UIImageView, you can follow as below

```
profileImageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width/2;

profileImageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

If you want to change your original image source to circle, you have to do some image drawing process.

Comment: Thanks but I want the actual cropper to display a round circle so the user can crop the image themselves as a circle with the same measurements. Does it make sense?